# set selected attribute using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, forms, html-select

I have a while loop that echoes option values to a select input and I'd like to use the html 'Selected' attribute so that the item chosen is retained after submit.

So, if the user selected 2, that item is still active in the select, rather than having it reset as it does currently.

Adding 'Selected' to the loop uses the last item. I do not know how to apply 'Selected' to the item that is being used only.

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <select name="object"><?php 

        $query = "SELECT object_id FROM objects";  
        $select_object_id = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_object_id)) {
        $object_description = $row['object_id'];
        echo "<option value='$object_description'>{$object_description}</option>";

        }
    ?>
        </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Select" />
    </form>
```

Comment: You just want the user to be able to select multiple options¿?

Comment: not quite, user selects one option but that option is retained so still visible as chosen in the dropdown list once data from selection is returned.

Comment: see the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<select name="object"><?php 

    $query = "SELECT object_id FROM objects";  
    $select_object_id = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_object_id)) {
    $object_description = $row['object_id'];
    echo "<option ";
    if($object_description == $_POST['object'])
        echo 'selected ';
    echo "value='$object_description'>{$object_description}</option>";

    }
?>
    </select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Select" />
</form>
```